# How to not break line after li and keep the bullet

Tags: html, css

I want to not break line after li and keep the bullet. meaning using the style: `display:inline` which removes the bullet is not good for me.

is there a way to do it?

this is what i have:

```
<ul class="c2">
    <div>
        <span>
           <li>line1</li>
           <li>line2</li>
           <li>line3</li>
           <li>line4</li>
       </span>        
       <span>I want this in same line as line4</span>
    </div>
</ul>
```

the problem is that whenever li is used since its display style is list-item, the line breaks

how it should look:

[image]

thank you!

Comment: Show what you have done

Comment: Side note: Your HTML isn't valid. You can't have div and span tags inside of ul tags like that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul. You can put a span within a li but not a ul tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:flex;`

```css
ul{
  display:flex;
}

li{
  margin-left:2rem;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
     <li>one</li>
     <li>two</li>
     <li>three</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Hey,
thanks for ur answer,
added some html with more explanation, this wont work

Comment: Hi @SagiCohen What is the final output that you are expecting :) Could you share an Image ?

Comment: added final output, but nvm i think ill do something else
thanks anyway!

Comment: Dear Friend @SagiCohen What you want to achieve is a total different thing that the question says. 
`I want to not break line after li ` This gives the perception that you want all the `li's` in a single row :) . 

Anyways, What you now want to achieve as per the image is straight forward. Give it a try (as you have said), If you couldn't find any solution, Do ping me later :)